Localization: $(x) R_{\mathfrak{m}}=R_{\mathfrak{m}}=\mathfrak{a} R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ for $x\in \mathfrak{a}$ but $x\notin \mathfrak{m}$
I have a commutative ring $R.$ Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be a non-zero ideal in this ring and $\mathfrak{m}$ be a maximal ideal. Also, let $x$ be a non-zero element of $\mathfrak{a}$ such that $x\notin \mathfrak{m}.$ By $R_{\mathfrak{m}},$ as always, we denote the localization $\left(R\setminus \mathfrak{m}\right)^{-1} R.$ Then my notes immediately say that
$$(x) R_{\mathfrak{m}}=R_{\mathfrak{m}}=\mathfrak{a} R_{\mathfrak{m}}.$$
I do not see how this must be obvious, so I would be grateful if someone could check my thoughts on that. Also, if someone can explain it better (i.e., in a way that I would be able to see it without writing any arguments out), I would appreciate it a lot.
I want to check that
$$(x) R_{\mathfrak{m}}=R_{\mathfrak{m}}=\mathfrak{a} R_{\mathfrak{m}},$$
where for an ideal $I$ in $R$ we denote by $I R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ the extension of this ideal in $R_{\mathfrak{m}},$ i.e., the ideal generated by the image of $I$ under the map $R\to R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ acting like that: $r\mapsto\frac{r}{1}.$
Let's prove that $R_{\mathfrak{m}} \subseteq (x) R_\mathfrak{m}.$ One can see that
$(x) R_{\mathfrak{m}}=\{ \frac{r}{s}\in R_\mathfrak{m} \mid r\in (x) ~ s\in R\setminus \mathfrak{m} \}.$ Let's take some element $\frac{r}{s}\in R_{\mathfrak{m}}.$ I want to find elements of $(x) R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ equal to that, so I am looking for $t\in R,~ p\in R\setminus \mathfrak{m}$ such that $\frac{r}{s}=\frac{tx}{p},$ i.e., I am looking for  $t\in R,~ p,u\in R\setminus \mathfrak{m}$ such that $u(pr-stx)=0.$ Take $t=r,~ p=sx$ (it certainly is in $R\setminus \mathfrak{m}$ since maximal ideals are prime) and any $u,$ then $u(sxr-srx)=0.$
Now let's prove that $R_{\mathfrak{m}} \subseteq \mathfrak{a} R_\mathfrak{m}.$ Again, given an arbitrary element $\frac{r}{s}\in R_{\mathfrak{m}}$ I want to find elements $a\in\mathfrak{a},~p,u\in R\setminus \mathfrak{m}$ such that $u(pr-sa)=0.$ We can take $p=sx$ and $a=rx$ and get $u(sxr-srx)=0.$
Thanks!

Since $x \not\in \mathfrak{m}$, we have that $x \in R \setminus \mathfrak{m}$. Therefore $x$ is a unit in $(R \setminus \mathfrak{m})^{-1}R = R_\mathfrak{m}$, so $(x) R_\mathfrak{m}$ is the unit ideal in $R_\mathfrak{m}$ (any ideal containing a unit must be equal to the entire ring). This shows that $(x) R_\mathfrak{m} = R_\mathfrak{m}$.
Moreover, $(x) \subseteq \mathfrak{a}$, so $R_\mathfrak{m} = (x)R_\mathfrak{m}  \subseteq \mathfrak{a} R_\mathfrak{m} \subseteq R_\mathfrak{m}$. So $R_\mathfrak{m} = \mathfrak{a}R_\mathfrak{m}$.

Thank you! That is exactly what I wanted. Also, if you could say whether my argument is correct, that would be even better, but in any case, you gave the full answer, and I am accepting it

Your argument is correct and it is the same as my argument (just with more details). You could take $p=sx$ because $sx$ is a unit in $R_\mathfrak{m}$.
